# How is the Gaussian distance weight being calculated in this bilateral filter code?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filtering

I read up on bilateral filtering from Wikipedia, all part of which I understand (I think).

So I'm trying to understand the implementation in Matlab, and got the code from [here](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12191-bilateral-filtering). I don't  understand the following part :

```
function B = bfltGray(A,w,sigma_d,sigma_r)

% Pre-compute Gaussian distance weights.
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-w:w,-w:w);
G = exp(-(X.^2+Y.^2)/(2*sigma_d^2));
```

I understand that the `meshgrid` function will give us 2 matrices `X` and `Y` which together will give me all possible combination of coordinates with x and y ranging from `-w` to `w` (where `2w+1` is the window size of the kernel). But I don't understand what `G = exp(-(X.^2+Y.^2)/(2*sigma_d^2));` accomplishes. Because for the spatial weight of (i,j), each neighbouring pixel (k,l) will contribute by something like

```
w(i,j,k,l) = exp(-((i-k)^2+(j-l)^2)/sigma_d^2)
```

In the code I understand how the Gaussian intensity weights are calculated because it's done at once like:

```
 % Compute Gaussian intensity weights.
 H = exp(-(I-A(i,j)).^2/(2*sigma_r^2));
```

whereas for Gaussian distance weights, again some computation is done :

```
% Calculate bilateral filter response.
F = H.*G((iMin:iMax)-i+w+1,(jMin:jMax)-j+w+1);
```

So basically, I don't understand how the Gaussian distance weights are being calculated.

Comment: What exactly is I? (in the H formula) Where is the i used for w?

Comment: That simply computes the spatial weights in a local neighborhood. I presume it’s re-used for all neighborhoods, so i and j are not necessary.

Comment: @PabloJeken I is the original image,(i,j) is the pixel we are filtering,(k,l) are the neighbouring pixels

Comment: What you are saying is actually making some sense to me, but I don't quite understand what are spatial weights and what's their use..any pointers? @CrisLuengo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bilateral filter computes a weighted average of pixels in the neighborhood of each pixel. Just like most other blur filters do. The difference with the bilateral filter is that it takes both the spatial distance **and** the tonal (intensity) distance into account when weighing.

For example, a normal Gaussian blur weighs pixels based on spatial distance only. A pixel that is at a distance `r` from the origin will be weighted with `exp(-0.5(r/s).^2)`, where `s` is the sigma (scaling) parameter of the Gaussian. It is important that all the weights sum up to one for the operation to be an averaging. This can be implemented as follows (modified from [the File Exchange submission linked in the OP](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12191-bilateral-filtering) -- `A` is the input image):

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-w:w,-w:w);
G = exp(-(X.^2+Y.^2)/(2*sigma_d^2));

dim = size(A);
B = zeros(dim);
for i = 1:dim(1)
  for j = 1:dim(2)
    % Extract local region.
    iMin = max(i-w,1);
    iMax = min(i+w,dim(1));
    jMin = max(j-w,1);
    jMax = min(j+w,dim(2));
    I = A(iMin:iMax,jMin:jMax);
    % Calculate Gaussian filter response.
    F = G((iMin:iMax)-i+w+1,(jMin:jMax)-j+w+1);
    B(i,j) = sum(F(:).*I(:))/sum(F(:));
  end
end
```

The `r^2` I mentioned earlier is computed with `X.^2+Y.^2`. `meshgrid` created arrays `X` and `Y` containing distances from the middle pixel to each pixel along the two axes. The code simply multiplies these weights `G` with the image values in the local neighborhood `I` and divides by the sum of the weights. The complication in the code comes from handling pixels close to the border of the image. Thus, near the border, `F` is a cropped version of `G`, and `I` is also extracted avoiding out-of-bounds indexing. The "computation" `G((iMin:iMax)-i+w+1,(jMin:jMax)-j+w+1)` is simply this cropping to get the right size neighborhood near the image edges.

The bilateral filter now adds a weighting based on the tonal distance (i.e. the difference in intensity for grey-value images). The kernel `F` is modified by multiplying it by:

```
H = exp(-(I-A(i,j)).^2/(2*sigma_r^2));
```

The distance now is `I-A(i,j)` -- `I` is the pixel values in the neighborhood, and `A(i,j)` is the pixel value in the center. The larger this value, the lower the weight used for that pixel.

Comment: I was missing the point that the even if the kernel moves over the entire image, the distances of neighbouring pixels from central pixel always remain same. Thank you so much for taking the time to explain nicely.